# Initial indexes for calculating the Fire Weather Index (in the Canadian Forest Fire Weather Index System)

Tags: weather-forecasting, forest, fossil-fuel, soil-moisture, drought

I am applying the Canadian Fire Weather Index (FWI) on the Forest Fire Warning System of my laboratory.

My problem is in calculating the Fine Fuel Moisture Code (FFMC), the Duff Moisture Code (DMC) and the Drought Code (DC) - 3 indicators for calculating FWI - the FWI has to use the values from the previous day as initial indexes. So, **How can I find the initial indexes for the first day of calculation?**